# Change height of UIImageView in Eureka TextRow

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiimageview, eureka-forms

Working on a captcha row in register form by Eureka with Swift.
I inserted a TextRow and assign the captcha image to `cell.imageView`, but the image is slightly taller that covered the row line. How can I change the height of that image?

Tried `cell.imageView?.frame`, not working.

Codes below. Many thanks.

```
<<< TextRow(){ row in
    row.title = ""
    row.tag = "Captcha"
    }.cellSetup { cell, row in
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data:imgData!, scale:1)
        //this line is not working
        cell.imageView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 98, height: 28)
    }
```

[image: screen shot]

Comment: did you use autolayout ?

Comment: @KKRocks I'm not sure. The imageView in the cell is defined by code (by Eureka), not on storyboard. But I guess so. The debugger says "[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints." when trying to change the height.

Comment: Maybe you are forcing the size with `scale:1`, did you try just passing the `data` argument?

Comment: @Efren Yes, but the `scale` part doesn't seem to affect anything. Remove it or change to another value have nothing different.

Comment: hmm, maybe setting `cell.height` ?

Comment: @Efren `cell` has `public var height: (()->CGFloat)?` not able to set

Comment: They do something weird in the container, not sure it sets it though: https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/blob/master/Example/Example/ViewController.swift#L1254

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144531/discussion-between-lol-wen-and-efren).

Answer (score 0):

Try to resize imageView using expected height

```
 cell.imageView?.image = self.resizeImage(image:  UIImage(data:imgData!, scale:1), expectedHeight: 28)

    func resizeImage(image: UIImage, expectedHeight: CGFloat) -> UIImage 
       {
            var image = image
            let scale = expectedHeight / image.size.height
            let newWidth = image.size.width * scale
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width :newWidth, height : expectedHeight))

            image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: expectedHeight))
            image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            return image
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried, not working. Debugger shows "[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints." Trying to dive to source code of Eureka. Is there any keyword links to "auto layout" or something I should aware of?